# How to load the PDF file, edit it, and save with the same name(automatically) in another path, in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net

I have a pdf format formular to be filled and saved with the same name. The pdf file should be loaded by calling the file in Adobe-pdfReader, then editing by operator and finally saving just by pushing the save button and automatically saving and naming by the software, not through saving-dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Sort of.

Before you show the `SaveFileDialog`, set it's FileName property to the name of your file. The only problem with this is that the user could still change the file name themselves. The code is simply

```
SaveFileDialog1.FileName = "your file name.txt"
SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
```

Unless you really need to have the dialog, you would be better saving it just using code. If you want to allow the user to choose the directory, use the `FolderBrowserDialog` instead.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I want to save the activated pdf file which has been just edited by the operator. But the fact is that it should be saved under a constant name by pushing the save button and no saving dialog.

Comment: Then also yes that should be possible, but what you want is completely different to your question. You need to supply more information  in your question. Without any code or information on any packages you are using, we have no hope of helping you - Have a look at [ask] thanks.